# Coloring plotly's boxplot box lines by factor

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot, color-coding

I have a `data.frame` with two `factor` variables (`type` and `age` in `df` below) and a single `numeric` variable (`value` in `df`) that I'd like to plot using `R`'s `plotly` package as a grouped `boxplot`.

Here's the `data.frame`:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(type = c(rep("t1", 1000), rep("t2", 1000), rep("t3", 1000), rep("t4", 1000), rep("t5", 1000), rep("t6", 1000)),
                 age = rep(c(rep("y", 500),rep("o", 500)), 6),
                 value = rep(c(runif(500, 5, 10), runif(500, 7.5, 12.5)), 6),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
df$age <- factor(df$age, levels = c("y", "o"), ordered = T)
```

Here's how I'm currently plotting it:

```
library(plotly)
library(dplyr)
plot_ly(x = df$type, y = df$value, name = df$age, color = df$type, type = "box", showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "Diversity"), boxmode = "group", boxgap = 0, boxgroupgap = 0)
```

Which gives:
[image]

My question is whether it is possible to color the lines of the boxes by `df$age`?

I know that for coloring all the boxes with a single color (e.g., `#AFB1B5`) I can add to the `plot_ly` function:

```
line = list(color = "#AFB1B5")
```

But that would color all box lines similarly whereas what I'm trying to do is to color them differently by `df$age`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do this that's not that too complicated, but rather ugly. Or something that is over the top cumbersome (I didn't realize how far I was digging until I was done...)

Before I go too far... I noticed that there is a ton of white space and that you have gaps set to zero. You can add the parameter `offsetgroup` and get rid of a lot more whitespace. Check it out:

```
plot_ly(data = df,
        x = ~type, y = ~value, name = ~age, offsetgroup = ~type, # <- I'm new!
        color = ~type, type = "box", showlegend = F) %>%
  layout(yaxis = list(title = "Diversity"), 
         boxmode = "group", boxgap = 0, boxgroupgap = 0)
```

[image]

##### With the not-too-complicated-but-kind-of-ugly method

The line is the box outline, the median line, the lines from Q1 to the lower fence, from Q3 to the upper fence, and the whiskers.

I assigned the plot to the object `plt` for this code. When I checked the object, it didn't have the data element, so I built the plot next.

```
plt <- plotly_build(plt)
```

Then I added colors with `lapply`.

```
# this looks ugly!
lapply(1:12,
       function(i){
         nm = plt$x$data[[i]]$name
         cr = ifelse(nm == "o",
                     "#66FF66", "black")
         plt$x$data[[i]]$line$color <<- cr  # change graph by age
       }
)
plt
```

[image]

##### With the ridiculous-amount-of-code-for-a-few-lines-but-looks-better method

I guess it isn't a *few* lines. It's 48 lines.

For this method, you need to build the plot like I did in the before (`plotly_build`), so that the data element is in the `plt` object.

Then you have to determine the first and third quantile, the IQR, the max and min values between the quantiles and 1.5 * IQR for each type and age grouping so that you have the y values for the lines.

I wrote a function to get the upper and lower fences.

```
fen <- function(vals){
  iq = 1.5 * IQR(vals)
  q3 = quantile(vals, 3/4)              # top of the box
  uf = q3 + iq                          # top of the fence
  vt = max(vals[vals > q3 & vals < uf]) # max value in range
  q1 = quantile(vals, 1/4)              # btm of the box
  bf = q1 - iq                          # btm of the fence
  vb = min(vals[vals < q1 & vals > bf]) # min value in range
  sz = function(no){
    if(length(no) > 1) {no = no[[1]]}
    return(no)
  }
  vt = sz(vt)
  vb = sz(vb)
  return(list(vt, vb))
}
```

Then I used this function and the data to determine the remaining values needed to draw the lines.

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  # have to reverse the order or it won't line up
  mutate(age = factor(age, levels = c("o", "y"), ordered = T)) %>% 
  group_by(type, age) %>% 
  summarise(ufen = fen(value)[[1]],     # top of the fence
            q3 = quantile(value, 3/4),  # top of the box
            q1 = quantile(value, 1/4),  # btm of the box
            dfen = fen(value)[[2]])     # btm of the fence
```

To plot these new lines, I used `shapes` which is equivalent to `ggplot2` annotations. (`annotations` in Plotly is primarily for text.)

There are several steps to drawing these lines. First I've started with some things that are essentially the same in every line. After that is a vector that helps place the lines on the x-axis.

```
# line shape basics; the same for every line
tellMe <- function(shade){
  list(type = "line",
       line = list(color = shade),
       xref = "paper",
       yref = "y")
}

# setup for placing lines on the x-axis; these are % of space
xers = c(rep(.0825, 4), rep(.083 * 3, 4), rep(.083 * 5, 4))
```

Now four `lapply` statements: the upper fences, the lower fences, the upper whiskers, and the lower whiskers.

```
lns <- lapply(1:12,
              function(i) {                     # upper fence lines
                nm = ifelse(df1[i, ]$age == "o",
                            "#66FF66", "black")
                xb = 1/12 * (i - 1)
                xn = xb + (1/6 * xers[[i]])
                more = tellMe(nm)
                c(x0 = xn, x1 = xn,
                  y0 = df1[i, ]$q3[[1]], # it's named; this makes it val only
                  y1 = df1[i, ]$ufen, more)
              })
mlns <- lapply(1:12,
               function(i) {                    # lower fence lines
                 nm = ifelse(df1[i, ]$age == "o",
                             "#66FF66", "black")
                 xb = 1/12 * (i - 1)
                 xn = xb + (1/6 * xers[[i]])
                 more = tellMe(nm)
                 c(x0 = xn, x1 = xn,
                   y0 = df1[i, ]$q1[[1]], # it's named; this makes it val only
                   y1 = df1[i, ]$dfen, more)
               })

# default whisker width is 1/2 the width of the box
# current boxes of 1/4 of the space by type
# with domain [0, 1], the box width is 1/12 * .5, so
# the whisker width is
ww = 1/12 * .5 *.5
# already have the center, so half on each side...
ww = ww * .5

wwlns <- lapply(1:12,
              function(i) {                     # upper fence whisker
                nm = ifelse(df1[i, ]$age == "o",
                            "#66FF66", "black")
                xb = 1/12 * (i - 1)
                xn = xb + (1/6 * xers[[i]])
                more = tellMe(nm)
                c(x0 = xn - ww, x1 = xn + ww,
                  y0 = df1[i, ]$ufen, y1 = df1[i, ]$ufen,
                  more)
              })
wwm <- lapply(1:12,
               function(i) {                     # lower fence whisker
                 nm = ifelse(df1[i, ]$age == "o",
                             "#66FF66", "black")
                 xb = 1/12 * (i - 1)
                 xn = xb + (1/6 * xers[[i]])
                 more = tellMe(nm)
                 c(x0 = xn - ww, x1 = xn + ww,
                   y0 = df1[i, ]$dfen, y1 = df1[i, ]$dfen,
                   more)
               })
```

Now you have to concatenate the lists and add them to the plot.

```
# combine shapes
shp <- append(lns, mlns)
shp <- append(shp, wwlns)
shp <- append(shp, wwm)

plt %>% layout(shapes = shp)
```

There are OBVIOUSLY better color choices out there.

[image]